# Android lock screen notification style functionality

Tags: android, android-notifications, lockscreen

I'm sort of new to developing Android applications. I'm building an Android 5 (Lollipop) application, which is so far nothing more than a tabbed activity with a single paragraph of text on every tab.

I want to show the first part of the paragraph on the lockscreen, in the style of a persistent notification or music player. Secondly I would like to go to the next or previous paragraph using the buttons on the lockscreen.

Can someone refer me to any guide or get me started?

Thanks alot

Comment: Please show what you've tried so far, and detail why it isn't working...

Comment: Sorry about that, someone edited my post and removed the actual question. I'm having trouble getting started somewhere.